# Can't play this video error in interstitial ad in android app

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

Can't play this video error in interstitial ad in android app. But before it works for me. Now only I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: do you have any error in the logs? did you try to debug?

Comment: It is from real device. Don't get any logs. Will try to get logs using any proxy.